# $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 1 $ then $y $ is monotone. True/false?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Consider  the ordinary differential equation

$$y'(x) = f(x) y(x) ,\quad x> 0 ,\quad y(0) = y_{0}  \neq 0.$$

Which of the following statements are true?

$1$. If $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx < \infty$, then  $y$ is  bounded.

$2$. If $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx < \infty$, then $\lim_{x \to  \infty} y(x)   $ exists.

$3$. If  $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1 $, then $lim_{x \to  \infty} |y(x)| = \infty$.

$4$. If  $\lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} f(x) = 1 $ then $y $  is monotone.

My attempts:  I know  that options  $1$, $2$, and $3$ are correct...but I'm doubting that option $4$  is  true.

Please help me; any hints/solutions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can write an explicit solution to the ODE. What is the derivative of $\ln {f}$?

Comment: @ copper .hat     that mean option 4 is True,,,if $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 1 $ then $y $ is monotone..can u elaborate more

Comment: Well, $y$ is monotone **iff** $y'$ does not change sign. What can you say about the sign of $y$ given that you have a formula for $y$?

Comment: okk  that  mean y will not  monotone..am I  right ??

Comment: Well, the sign of $y$ will not change, but you can change $f$ so that $y'$ changes sign and still have $f(x) \to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is continuous and $y_0>0$  and $y(x)=y_0\cdot e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x)=\int_0^xf(u)du.$ Suppose $f(1)=f(2)=0$ and that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in [0,1)\cup (2,\infty)$ and $f(x)<0$ for $x\in (1,2).$ And suppose that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1.$

We have $y(2)-y(1)=$ $y_0\cdot e^{g(1)}\cdot (e^{g(2)-g(1)}-1).$ Now $g(2)-g(1)=\int_1^2f(u)du<0$ so $f(2)<f(1).$

We have $y(1)-y(0)=y_0\cdot e^{g(0)}\cdot (e^{g(1)-g(0)}-1).$ Now $g(1)-g(0)=\int_0^1 f(u)du>0$ so $f(1)>f(0).$

Remark. If $y>0$   then $yf=y'\implies f=y'/y=(\ln y)'$ which implies   that $\ln y$ is an anti-derivative of $f$.